# retrieve data from file, put in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to figure out the best method for retrieving data from a file and putting it in an array. The final goal is to create a dictionary for a game so that I can validate words that were submitted by a user.

Although I'm still new programming, I've done some research and it seems that .get function may allow that. Before I embark on building all of that code, I wanted to check to see if my starting logic was correct.

If I have a file called wordcheck.txt and it has thousands of words. Can I retrieve the data by

```
$.get(workcheck.txt, functions(words) {
var wordArray = words.split( "\n");
}
```

I haven't figured out where to go to from here yet, but I wanted to make sure I was understanding the beginning correctly.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens?

Comment: Excuse me if it wasn't clear. I tried it. I don't want to continue writing the code because I wasn't sure I was misunderstanding this part.

Comment: +1 because you seem genuinely interested in learning. But you should probably spend some more time researching before you post questions here. Research is, after all, the *best* way to learn.

Comment: I think what Andy means is that if you run that piece of code, you'll discover quickly whether it works, whether you've accidentally included syntax errors (which Andy has outlined in his answer), etc. The main issue is that the question is somewhat open ended and vague in terms of what you're specifically asking. If you're new to programming, consider building your programs in smaller testable pieces so that you can run or analyze them individually, and thus be able to resolve a lot of logical and syntactical issues before you write any other pieces.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Add quotes around the file you're trying to load.

2) You might want to define `wordArray` before you do the `$.get` otherwise the data won't be available outside of that anonymous function.

3) It's `function` not `functions`.

4) You missed a closing `)`.

```
var wordArray;
$.get('workcheck.txt', function (words) {
  wordArray = words.split('\n');
});
```